# What can i do so that allah forgivess me

Tags: halal-haram

Hi i am a 13 year old boy i started wanking 2019 in december and i stopped a week ago. I stopped beacuse i went and searched  it up and it said that it is haram. I would like to know what i should do so that allah can forgive me? I would like someone to tell me what will happen next abd if i would be forgiven for the sin that i have made. I have tried to search a answer but i could not find one

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum brother,
I'm happy to read that Allah سبحانہ وتعالی gave you strength to realize that you are doing a sin and you should do a remedy for it.
Its a great blessing of Allah to make someone realize their mistake.

My brother don't worry, Allah سبحانہ وتعالی is very Kind and Merciful , He forgives everything except shirk, as He said in Surah no.4 (Al-Nisa) verse no.48 :
إِنَّ اللَّهَ لاَ يَغْفِرُ أَن يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ ذَلِكَ لِمَن يَشَاء
(Surely  Allah does not forgive that anything should be associated with Him, and He forgives what is less than that for whom He pleases.)

And Numerous Prophetic hadiths celebrate and stress the issue of repentance such as the one narrated by Anas ibn Malik in Sahih Al-Bukhari which reads what may mean,
“Allah is more pleased with the repentance of His slave than anyone of you is pleased with finding his camel which he had lost in the desert.” (Al-Bukhari)

So anything which is less than "shirk" can be forgiven if we ask forgiveness from Allah سبحانہ وتعالی, and asking forgiveness from Allah is called توبۃ (tauba) and for tauba there are 5 conditions that must be followed and Allah will forgive ان شاء اللہ .

1-To be sincere to Allah.
You have to be sincere to Allah because the forgiveness woukd not be given to you if you are insincere to Him and as He knows what is there in your heart so there is no use of being insincere to Him.

2-To regret one’s past evil deeds.
You have to be really sad and you must regret for what you've already done in the past.

3-To give up sinning.
You have to leave sinning otherwise there is no use of asking forgiveness, if you really want your repentance to be accepted then you must give up sinning and start a sin free life.

4-To make a firm resolve of avoiding such sins in the future.
You have to make promise to Allah سبحانہ وتعالی that you won't repeat this sin ever again.

5-To show repentance while it is still valid.
You must ask forgiveness before its too late , as when a person is dying then asking forgiveness is of no use.

Such Tauba (repentance) will surely be accepted by Allah سبحانہ وتعالی and my brother you'll be forgiven and will be free from sin ان شاء اللہ.

I hope it helps brother.
Wassalam.

References :
https://aboutislam.net/shariah/refine-your-heart/advice/repentance-and-its-conditions/
https://alquranalmajeed.com/4-al-nisa/4-48